# get resolved parameters in a bundle extension class

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm writing a Symfony bundle and I need to setup a service definition in my Extension class depending on the value of a configuration parameter.

An it works fine, as long as you don't try to use any expressions in the parameter value.

My extension class looks like this:

```
class MyBundleExtension extends Extension
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = $this->getConfiguration($configs, $container);
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        
        dd($config['custom_param']);
    }

    ...
}
```

In my application, I set the parameter like this:

**.env.local:**

```
MY_BUNDLE_CUSTOM_PARAM=blah
```

**config.yaml:**

```
parameters:
    my_bundle_custom_param: '%env(MY_BUNDLE_CUSTOM_PARAM)%'
```

```
my_bundle:
    custom_param: '%my_bundle_custom_param%'
```

The problem is, that in the Extension class, this parameter is not yet resolved, so `dd()` shows this:

```
"env_de85db6c4d65707d_MY_BUNDLE_CUSTOM_PARAM_71f5c271abfed252c958c82c1e3fb8dc"
```

instead of the expected `blah`.

Is there any way to get the resolved value of the parameter in the Extension class?

Comment: Basically no.  Extension classes are run during compile time and not during each request.  Env variables can be changed at any time to you can't cache their value.  You need to define your services to use parameters and the system will take care of the rest.

Comment: What if I move my logic into a compiler pass? 
In the extension, I'd only have 
`$container->setParameter('my_bundle.custom_param', $config['custom_param'] ?? null);` and in the compiler pass I'd get the resolved value with:
`$container->resolveEnvPlaceholders($container->getParameter('my_bundle.custom_param'), true);`.
It seems to work, but I'm not sure if there'd be any potential problems with such approach.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  The point of using env's is that their value can change for each request.  If you just want a fixed value then use a regular parameter.  No need for env's.  It might help to make a simple test case and then walk through the generated container to see what goes on under the hood.

Comment: The main goal is to allow expressions for the configuration parameter of the bundle.
It is just a specific use case I have where I want to use env variable in that expression to override the value for my local dev machine only

Comment: Other bundles resolve this by configuring such parameters in the application's configuration directory, like https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/blob/master/trikoder/oauth2-bundle/2.0/config/packages/trikoder_oauth2.yaml which is stored in `config/packages` (and not in the `vendor` directory) - maybe this helps?

Comment: the difference in my case is that I need the resolved param value in the Extension/CompilerPass, while typically (such as the case with trikoder) the params are needed resolved during DI. (https://github.com/sineflow/ElasticsearchBundle/blob/b9aeb42b060d1c96330af791710488d92ad4b383/DependencyInjection/Compiler/SetCachePass.php#L20)

Answer (score 0):

You gave the correct answer in your comment:

```
/**
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container): void
{

    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config        = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
    $resolve       = $container->resolveEnvPlaceholders($config, true);
    $config['upload_path'] = \str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $resolve['upload_directory']);
    $container->setParameter("mybundle", $config);
```